# Does UsbDeviceConnection requestWait() method block?

Tags: android, usb

As the title says, in Android's `UsbDeviceConnection`, does the `requestWait()` method block until it is able to read something (assuming it was initialized on the read endpoint of the device).

If so, is there a way to interrupt this wait through timeout or something else?

Comment: do you mean UsbDeviceConnection?

Comment: the documentation seems to say that this is indeed blocking for an IN endpoint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android usb requestWait not return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781807/android-usb-requestwait-not-return)

Comment: Yes, it does block, and no, you can't interrupt it. Unless you closes the usbrequest instance